# getBoundingClientRect() returns zero

Tags: javascript, html

What the below code does is it creates a span with specific dimensions and position (Offered by getBoundingClientRect) when the mouse is hovered over an `<a>` tag and this works fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ollow Along Nav</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="">consectetur</a> adipisicing elit. Est <a href="">explicabo</a> unde natus necessitatibus esse obcaecati distinctio, aut itaque, qui vitae!</p>
      <p>Aspernatur sapiente quae sint <a href="">soluta</a> modi, atque praesentium laborum pariatur earum <a href="">quaerat</a> cupiditate consequuntur facilis ullam dignissimos, aperiam quam veniam.</p>
    </div>

<script>
  const triggers = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  const highlight = document.createElement('span');
  highlight.classList.add('highlight');
  document.body.appendChild(highlight);

  function highlightLink(a) {
    const linkCoords = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    const coords = {
      width: linkCoords.width,
      height: linkCoords.height,
      top: linkCoords.top + window.scrollY,
      left: linkCoords.left + window.scrollX
    };

    highlight.style.width = `${coords.width}px`;
    highlight.style.height = `${coords.height}px`;
    highlight.style.transform = `translate(${coords.left}px, ${coords.top}px)`;

  }

  triggers.forEach(a => highlightLink(a));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to create a unit testing for the above code in the script tag So I came up with this NodeJS based script

```
const index = require('./index.js');
//runs the html in express app


var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

const test =async()=>{

   const request = require('supertest');
  const response = await request(index).get("/");
 
  document.body.innerHTML = response.text;
  const triggers = document.querySelectorAll('a')
  var highlight = document.createElement('span');
highlight.classList.add('highlight');
document.body.appendChild(highlight);
  

  function checkThis(a) {
      
    const linkCoords = a.getBoundingClientRect();
 console.log(linkCoords.width)

    }
    triggers.forEach(a => checkThis(a));
} 

  
test()
```

For some reason, I am getting the width as zero for all the `<a>` tags. Even the other properties from `getBoundingClientRect` are zero. What could be the possible reasons for it?. And what will be the best way to test this code using Jest and Supertest?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DOM is ready. Before you bind events or access elements. Also, you'll always get zeros if element you're trying to access has `display:none`.

To check if the problem is that the DOM is loaded too late, just log your *triggers* variable and see if it has the right values, if it doesn't, you coudl do this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // put code that needs to wait for DOM to load here
})
```